# ajax function not running on page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Okay im using a MVC yii framework. At the moment i have a table of details that relate to categories.

So i have 3 categories, a main category subcategory and child category. These drop down lists (select options) are populated from the database via ajax request.

So "on change" the main category it runs this function

```
    function getSubcategory(){

        var firstcategory = $('#casesearch-category').val();
            var childcategory = document.getElementById('casesearch-childcategory');
            childcategory.options.length = 0;
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('cases/subcategories') ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                    firstcategory: firstcategory 
                },
                success: function(data) {      

                    var subcategory = document.getElementById('casesearch-subcategory');
                    //if select is changed again, make the options length 0 so that it gets rid of previous appends.
                    subcategory.options.length = 0;


                    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        subcategory.options[i] = new Option (data[i].name);
                        subcategory.options[i].value = data[i].subcategory_id;
                    }
                    subcategory.options.selectedIndex = -1;
                }
            });
    }
```

Okay so this basically sends the value of the first category to my controller.

```
public function actionSubcategories()
{
   if(Yii::$app->request->post('firstcategory')){
        $firstcategory = Yii::$app->request->post('firstcategory');
        // SELECT * FROM `subcategory` WHERE `parent_id` = $firstcategory
        $subcategory = Subcategory::findSubcategory($firstcategory);

    }    
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($subcategory);
}
```

Okay so this then goes back to my view and populates the subcategory drop down with the correct subcategories that correspond to the main category.

This is great is works fine , the ajax request to get the child category does pretty much the same as the one above so i wont include this.

So finally when i press the submit button. It grabs all the values of each category and then it will populate a table with details that correspond to the specific categories.

This works great, however the problem is, when the page is submitted i wont the drop down lists to be already populated with the values that where posted. But without manually setting in php.

I send through to the view the first category and then call

```
 getSubcategory();
```

This should then loop the whole process again, but it doesn't. Im stuck on this can anyone help.

If you need more code or anything please ask and i will update my question.

Comment: You can't set `length` like you do with `subcategory.options.length = 0` (etc). It's a read-only property. You can set `selectedIndex`, but the method takes a string, not a number: `options.selectedIndex = '-1'`. Is your submit handled by ajax? If not you'll have to pass back the values from php to the `getSubcategory()` somehow.